# Custom RSS causing timeout for website

Tags: feed

I have a WordPress news site, which requires a custom RSS feed to be sent to a certain distributor.

The issue is, that while the custom feed replaces the original one, it causes a timeout about every two hours, and I can't figure out what is causing the potential overload. Here's the code:

```php
    <?php
    /**
     * RSS2 Feed Template for displaying RSS2 Posts feed.
     *
     * @package WordPress
     */
    
    header( 'Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type( 'rss2' ) . '; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ), true );
    $more = 1;
    
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) . '"?' . '>';
    
    /**
     * Fires between the xml and rss tags in a feed.
     *
     * @since 4.0.0
     *
     * @param string $context Type of feed. Possible values include 'rss2', 'rss2-comments',
     *                        'rdf', 'atom', and 'atom-comments'.
     */
    do_action( 'rss_tag_pre', 'rss2' );
    ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:hst="http://hirstart.hu/rss-mod"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
    <?php // do_action( 'rss2_ns' ); ?>

    <channel>
        <title><?php // wp_title_rss(); ?> Tőzsdefórum | Minden ami tőzsde</title>
        <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link><?php bloginfo_rss( 'url' ); ?></link>
        <description><?php bloginfo_rss( 'description' ); ?></description>
        <lastBuildDate><?php echo get_feed_build_date( 'r' ); ?></lastBuildDate>
        <language><?php bloginfo_rss( 'language' ); ?></language>
        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>

        <?php
        // do_action( 'rss2_head' );

        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            ?>
        <item>
            <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
            <?php
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $kiemelt = get_field( 'kiemelt_cikk' );
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
            $img = get_headers($image[0], 1);
            

            if ( is_array( $kiemelt ) ) {
                if ( in_array( 'igen', $kiemelt ) ) {

                    $output = '<hst:titlepage>1</hst:titlepage>';
                    echo $output;
                }
            }?>
            <link><?php the_permalink_rss(); ?></link>
            <?php if ( get_comments_number() || comments_open() ) : ?>
            <comments><?php comments_link_feed(); ?></comments>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <dc:creator>
                <![CDATA[<?php the_author(); ?>]]>
            </dc:creator>
            <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', true ), false ); ?>
            </pubDate>
            <?php the_category_rss( 'rss2' )?>
            <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
            <enclosure url="<?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail_url();
                }
                ?>" length="<?php 
                if ( $img ) {
                echo $img["Content-Length"];
                }?>" type="image/jpg" />

            <?php if ( get_option( 'rss_use_excerpt' ) ) : ?>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]>
            </description>
            <?php else : ?>
            <description>
                <![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]>
            </description>
            <?php $content = get_the_content_feed( 'rss2' ); ?>
            <?php if ( strlen( $content ) > 0 ) : ?>
            <content:encoded>
                <![CDATA[<?php echo $content; ?>]]>
            </content:encoded>
            <?php else : ?>
            <content:encoded>
                <![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>]]>
            </content:encoded>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( get_comments_number() || comments_open() ) : ?>
            <wfw:commentRss><?php echo esc_url( get_post_comments_feed_link( null, 'rss2' ) ); ?></wfw:commentRss>
            <slash:comments><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></slash:comments>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php rss_enclosure(); ?>

            <?php
            /**
             * Fires at the end of each RSS2 feed item.
             *
             * @since 2.0.0
             */
            do_action( 'rss2_item' );
            ?>
        </item>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

The only error I'm able to find being repeated in the log is the following:

```
[17-Jan-2023 11:43:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  get_headers(https://website.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Civita-Tanyer2-1-scaled-1.jpg): Failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/tozsdefo/public_html/wp-content/themes/tozsdeforum-theme/feed-rss2.php on line 49
[17-Jan-2023 11:43:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/tozsdefo/public_html/wp-content/themes/tozsdeforum-theme/feed-rss2.php on line 71
[17-Jan-2023 11:43:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  get_headers(): SSL: Handshake timed out in /home/tozsdefo/public_html/wp-content/themes/tozsdeforum-theme/feed-rss2.php on line 51
[17-Jan-2023 11:43:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  get_headers(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/tozsdefo/public_html/wp-content/themes/tozsdeforum-theme/feed-rss2.php on line 51
[17-Jan-2023 11:43:05 UTC] PHP Warning:  get_headers(https://website.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/orr-shutterstock_1882856173.jpg): Failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/tozsdefo/public_html/wp-content/themes/tozsdeforum-theme/feed-rss2.php on line 51
[17-Jan-2023 11:43:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  get_headers(https://website.hu/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/food_truck_show-1.jpg): Failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/tozsdefo/public_html/wp-content/themes/tozsdeforum-theme/feed-rss2.php on line 51
```

I removed the domain of the website from the error log (website.hu)
Any suggestions as to what might be causing the overload?

Comment: are you sure that `$img = get_headers($image[0], 1);` does what you think it does? `get_headers` has nothing to do with images, that line is incorrect and makes no sense, and it involves a HTTP request which is one of the slowest most expensive things you can do in a template. I suspect this is an attempt to figure out the size of the image? You can do that without using the images URL or making a HTTP request to download it. There's also no error handling at all, if it fails it returns `false` which you don't check for, leading to problems

Comment: As @TomJNowell mentioned, using `get_headers()` here is weird. I'll post an alternative in an answer below, but is this the entire original file? The second error about array offset also seems weird so maybe check whatever is on line 71.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomJNowell mentioned it's weird to use `get_headers()` for this. It would be better to remove the `$img` variable entirely and just use `strlen()` in your enclosure to get the length of the string in bytes:

```
<enclosure url="<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail_url();
    }
    ?>" length="<?php 
        if ( $image ) {
            echo strlen( $image[0] );
        }?>" type="image/jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the issue exactly. I thank you all for the help!